# What's the name of this theorem ($f>g$ given $f'>g'$ and initial value)?

Tags: calculus

I need to use this theorem as part of a proof. Basically it goes as follows:

If $f(x_0) > g(x_0)$ and $\frac{d}{dx} f(x) > \frac{d}{dx} g(x)$ for all $x \geq x_0$, then $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x\geq x_0$.

What's the name of this theorem, if it has one? Or if it doesn't, is there a simple way to prove it that I could include in my proof? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: it follows directly from the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 5):

This is commonly called [the Racetrack principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racetrack_principle).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Consider $$h=f-g$$

You have then that $$h'>0$$ and that $$h(x_0)>0$$

Why must then $h$ **remain positive** for $x\geq x_0$?

**Spoiler**

> If $f'>0$ on some domain $D$; then $f$ is increasing on $D$.