# Is there a theorem that gives this result?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $(c,\delta)\in\mathrm{K}^2\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f,g:\mathrm{K}\to\mathbb{R}$ be $C^1$
$$f(c)=g(c),\,f'(x)\geq g'(x)\,\,\forall x\in[c,c+\delta]\implies f(x)\geq g(x)\,\,\forall x\in[c,c+\delta]$$

Comment: This seems to be a corollary of the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: It's sometimes known as the [Racetrack principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/210207/2785).  If two horses start at the same point on a track, but one runs faster, the faster one will always be ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $h(x):=f(x)-g(x)$. We have $h(c)=0$.

Suppose $h(x)<0$ for some $x\in[c, c+\delta]$. By mean value theorem, there exists $x\in[c, x]$ such that $h'(x)<0$.

Thus, $\exists x\in[c, c+\delta]$ such that $f(x)<g(x)\Longrightarrow\exists x\in[c, c+\delta]$ such that $f'(x)<g'(x)$.

The contrapositive of this is the statement you gave.

Comment: I think you mean $f'(x) < g'(x)$.

Comment: @martycohen Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Theorem says that definite integral of non-negative function is non-negative. Here, non-negative function is $f'(x)-g'(x)$ (which is integrable, as $f$ and $g$ are $C^1$ functions, so their derivatives and hence, difference of derivatives is continuous and therefore integrable) , and interval of non-negativity is $[c,t]$ where, $t\in (c, c+\delta]$
$$\Longrightarrow \int_{c}^{t} f'(x)-g'(x)dx\geq 0$$
$$\Longrightarrow \int_{c}^{t} f'(x)dx-\int_{c}^{t} g'(x)dx\geq 0$$
Now, apply fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: You've added an assumption that the derivatives are integrable, but that's very often easy to show.  For instance, if $f$ is $C^1$, then $f'$ is continuous, and so $f'$ is also integrable.

Comment: @Matthew Leingang, added that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By considering $f-g$ we can without loss of generality assume that $g=0$ and $f(c)=0$.

Then by the mean value theorem we have for some $c\leqslant x_1<c+\delta$ that
$$
f(x)=f(x)-f(c)=(x-c)f'(x_1)\geqslant 0.
$$